# Drawing polygons interactively in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I am writing a program in which the user left-clicks in at least 3 places and when the user right-clicks, a polygon is drawn, with these places as vertices. The frame is created but the program does not work. It says **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**. I don't understand why.

I am new to Java graphics and it is the first time I use MouseListener.

**The Main class:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DrawPolygon dp = new DrawPolygon();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Draw Polygon");
        f.getContentPane().add(dp);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(700,700);
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

**The DrawPolygon class:**

```
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class DrawPolygon extends JPanel implements MouseListener 
{
    int Vertices = 0; //to store number of vertices

    //use vector instead of array because dynamic structure is required as there can be any number of vertices >= 3
    Vector<Integer> PolyX = new Vector<Integer>(3,1); //to store x coordinates
    Vector<Integer> PolyY = new Vector<Integer> (3,1); //to store y coordinates

    Polygon poly; //polygon to draw

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) //left button is clicked - creating new vertex for polygon
        {
            Vertices++; //new polygon vertex is created
            PolyX.addElement(e.getX()); //store x coordinates in vector
            PolyY.addElement(e.getY()); //store y coordinates in vector
        }
        else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) //right button is clicked - instruction to draw polygon
        {
            if (Vertices < 3) //a polygon has at least 3 vertices
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There must be at least 3 clicks.");
            }
            else //draw polygon
            {
                //create array to pass coordinates to Polygon which accepts only int[] as coordinates
                int[] xPoints = new int[PolyX.size() - 1];
                int[] yPoints = new int[PolyY.size() - 1];
                //copy coordinates from vector to array
                for (int i = 0; i < Vertices; i++)
                {
                    xPoints[i] = PolyX.elementAt(i + 1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Vertices; i++)
                {
                    yPoints[i] = PolyY.elementAt(i + 1);
                }
                //draw polygon
                poly = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints, Vertices);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D graphx = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphx.draw(poly);
    }
}
```

**The full error message:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2461)
    at assignment1.DrawPolygon.paintComponent(DrawPolygon.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5224)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1532)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1455)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1252)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1039)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2461)
    at assignment1.DrawPolygon.paintComponent(DrawPolygon.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5224)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1532)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1455)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1252)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1039)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Include the error stacktrace.

Comment: You should indicate in the code you posted the line where this error occured

Comment: I added the full error message to the post.

Comment: Your `paintComponent` method is likely being called before you've initialized `poly`.

Comment: Where should I place the `paintComponent` method?

Comment: It's not that you should put the method somewhere else, but you shouldn't have it draw a polygon that doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: it's not a question of where to put the paintComponent method. You need to make sure that before it is shown of the screen that your "poly" variable has been initialized

Comment: I don't really understand in which order the different methods are executed. In any case the problem comes from poly not having been initialised. So, where should I initialise it and assign its parameters?

Comment: Please check my edited answer. With some small changes your code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is flawed at multiple Points:

1.Only implementing MouseListener isn't enough, you have to register it:

```
public DrawPolygon() {
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

2.False assumtion according the length of the Vertices-Vector:
why *PolyX.elementAt(i + 1)*??

3.JPanel has to be repainted when the Polygon has changed. At the end of *mouseClicked* call *repaint();*

4.Only draw the polygon if already initialized like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if (poly != null) {
        Graphics2D graphx = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphx.draw(poly);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenGL, think of what a Polygon is, it's a shape made of many triangles, for example if the shape is a cube, you would need 12 triangles, made from floats:

```
Float[] polygon = {1.0f , 0.0f};
```

You know how it works anyway, and watch the polygon count as well, the more triangles the longer it takes to render.